# How to calculate user posts

Tags: count

I have table users with about 220 k users and each user made almost 1 post

table users 
and in field i have the number of he's post's postcount=5

I want to know the sum of all users postcount

thnakx in advance

Comment: Using SQL?  Where is your query you are having trouble with now?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(postcount) FROM users;
```

Try this query.